# Sub-pixel Image rendering

Tags: java, graphics

I am aware of sub-pixel shapes, such as `Rectangle2D.Double`, `Ellipse2D.Double` and `Line2D.Double` - but I couldn't find information about drawing an `Image` / `BufferedImage` with sub-pixel accuracy.

Perhaps something that would look like this - `Image2D.Double`?

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Images may be drawn with an [AffineTransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html), which can specify scaling and translation with floating point values.

(See [drawImage(Image, AffineTransform, ImageObserver)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20java.awt.geom.AffineTransform,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) method)

For example, to draw an image scaled to half size and at position (10.5, 10.5), use:

```
Graphics2D g = ...
BufferedImage myImage = ...
AffineTransform t = new AffineTransform();
t.translate(10.5, 10.5);
t.scale(0.5, 0.5);
g.drawImage(myImage, t, null);
```

You should ensure that appropriate [RenderingHints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html) have been set on the Graphics2D object (set `KEY_ANTIALIASING` to `VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON` for starters).