# Drawing an Image in Java with Sub Pixel Accuracy

Tags: java, image, graphics2d, subpixel

How can I draw an image in java with sub pixel accuracy?

I found similar questions here:

[Drawing an image using sub-pixel level accuracy using Graphics2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676909/drawing-an-image-using-sub-pixel-level-accuracy-using-graphics2d)

[Sub-pixel Image rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335340/sub-pixel-image-rendering)

Unfortunately the solutions provided within the answers does not work for me.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2.translate(50.5, 50.5);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, 15, 25);
}
```

Using `g2.translate(50.5, 50.5);` to fill a simple rectangale with sub pixel accuracy works nicely.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2.translate(50.5, 50.5);
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

However when I use `g2.translate(double x, double y)`to draw an image with sub pixel accuracy, it doesn't work. It's exactly the same result as drawing with integer positions.

Why is this not working? I translated the graphics with double values, yet I'm not seeing any interpolation between pixels.

Comment: I am not sure which version of Java you use. The signature of `drawImage` should be `drawImage(BufferedImage img, BufferedImageOp op, int x, int y)` afaik. - Correction: Both signatures seem to exist in different versions. What JDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java 13. I tried `drawImage(BufferedImage img, BufferedImageOp op, int x, int y)` as well, but I still do not see any interpolation between pixels.

Comment: One hack that might work, is set up a `TexturePaint` using your image, and use that to fill a rectangle the same size of your original image (and with the half pixel offset, as in your first code sample).

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see any interpolation =(

Comment: Well, works for me.. Java 8u181 on MacOS. Not sure what kind of interpolation you expect to see though...

Comment: I'm running on a Win8 machine, I tried using Java 8 as well, but no luck :V
I'm expecting the edges of the image to be slightly transparent, since the position is represented by a double, but it's showing a completely opaque edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be OS or Java version dependent, but for me*, using `TexturePaint` (which I consider somewhat of a hack) works:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2.translate(50.5, 50.5);
    // g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); // Original code
    g2.setPaint(new TexturePaint(image, new Rectangle(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight())));
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

    // Added orange rect for reference, as the difference is hard to spot...
    g2.setPaint(Color.ORANGE);
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, 15, 25);
}
```

*) on MacOS 10.15, tested with both Java 8 and 11.

You might need to zoom in to see the difference, as it is kind of subtle... But in the first image (`drawImage`), you'll see the orange rect does not overlap perfectly, and the edges of the image are solid. In the second image (`TexturePaint` and `fillRect`) you'll see the edges of the image is translucent, and the orange rect overlaps perfectly.

[image: screenshot of running program]

Here's the same application running on my MacBooks internal "retina" screen:

[image: screenshot of running program on high res screen]

Comment: IT WORKS AAAAAAA

Thank you so much, I'm still very unsure of why it didn't work when I initially tried it from your comment, but it's working on both Java 8 and Java 13 now, thanks!